# Dynamic Actionlinks

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using asp.net mvc 4 and I have the following scenario

```
Cities           Places     Events
------           ------------------
City 1          |                  
City 2          |
                |
```

The left navigation (cities) list all of the cities in database. Places and Events also are links to action methods.

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Places", "Places", null, new{id="placeslink"})</li>
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Events", "Events", null, new{id="eventslink"})</li>
```

I am asynchronously loading Places and Events using the following script (jQuery)

```
$('#placeslink').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#content').html(ajax_load).load(url);
});

$('#eventslink').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#content').html(ajax_load).load(url);
});
```

Its is working fine and populates all the places (not city specific) and Events on the page from database when Places and Events links are clicked.

Now what I want to achieve is that when user click a city while viewing places, only the places in that city are displayed and if events are selected, the same city link should display the events in that city.
Similary if a city (e.g City 1) is selected and user click places, places in the selected city are displayed and if she clicks Events, events for the selected city are display.

I have the following action methods

```
public ActionResult Places()
{
  if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
  {
     ....  
     return PartialView(model);               

  }
  return View();
}
```

Its quite confusing and I cannot think of a single way how to generate appropriate links for City, places and events and achieve the above mentioned results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving this a try, I would make the view model like this

```
public class PlacesAndEventsViewModel
{
    public string LocationOption { get; set; }  //places or events

    public List<Place> Places { get; set; }

    public List<Event> Events { get; set; }

    public int? CityID { get; set; }
}
```

And my controller

```
//this is get
public ActionResult  ShowLocations()
{
    var model = new PlacesAndEventsViewModel();

    model.CityID = null; //or any default value
    model.LocationOption = "places"; //or any default value
    model.Places = new List<Place>(); //or GetAllPlacesFromDB();
    //You can do the same for events but I think you need one at a time

    return View("ViewPlaces", model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult  ShowLocations(PlacesAndEventsViewModel model)
{
    if(model.LocationOption == "places")
    {
        model.Places = GetAllPlacesByCity(model.CityID);
        return View("ViewPlaces", model);   //All these could be partial view
    }
    else if(model.LocationOption == "cities")
    {
        model.Events = GetAllEventsByCity(model.CityID);
        return View("ViewEvents", model);  //All these could be partial view
    }
    else
    {
        return View("ViewPlaces", model);  //All these could be partial view
    }
}
```

You might need to change your Ajax to $.ajax()

```
  $.ajax({
     url: '@Url.Action("ShowLocation"),
     data: { LocationOption: '@Model.LocationOption', CityID: @Model.CityID }
  });
```